# Angular Breadcrumbs : Is it possible to show breadcrumbs without altering the route?

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

There is a requirement in my project to show **breadcrumbs** while
    navigating to the folders in UI without changing the UI Route (route in
    URL bar)

The Breadcrumb which our team is using [Angular-Breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb)  uses *UI-Router* to formulate breadcrumbs, but i want to change breadcrumb for some actions which don't alter the route

**Note :**

> I did googling and most of the solutions based on the **Route** only,
>   so decided to ask you folks if someone did this earlier. Just approach to the solution  is
>   fine with me not searching for entire solution will be more than happy to
>   implement it myself

Comment: Did u find any solution?